# Is radial basis function network appropriate for small datasets?

Tags: neural-networks, machine-learning, deep-learning, supervised-learning

I'm a computer engineering student and I'm about to work on my master thesis. My professor gave me a small dataset with brain Computed Axial Tomography records. I would like to use deep learning to help doctors diagnose a certain disease (obviously, I've also got the data for doing supervised learning).

Since the dataset is small, is [radial basis function network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radial_basis_function_network) a good solution? What do you think?

Btw, if you have any type of tips in using the RBF network for this kind of project I would be really grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not familiar with RBF but when you have a small data set image augmentation can help. You can do this easily with the Keras ImageDataGenerator, documentation is [here](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/). Alternatively you can create image augmentation yourself using image processing models like PIL or CV2.